# Why is Windows 7 giving me a software counterfeiting error?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, parallels-desktop

I have a legitimate copy of Windows 7 Ultimate installed via Bootcamp on my Macbook Pro.  I also have Parallels 5 installed on my Mac OS X, which can boot up Bootcamp's partition of Windows 7.

I'm getting an error when I run Windows 7 on Parallels:

> You may be a victim of software counterfeiting

It wants me to go online and resolve it.  But I've already registered my copy of Windows 7 (I can't remember if I did it via Bootcamp or Parallels).

My question is: **Does my single copy of Windows 7 only allow me to have it installed via Bootcamp or Parallels?**

I only installed it once, and my copy of Parallels is booting my Bootcamp install.  It's the same machine!  I'm hoping I don't need to have 2 licenses of Windows 7 run it on my Macbook Pro!

Comment: you just need to install once your legitimate copy via bootcamp and use it via parallels-desktop

Comment: @Am1rr3zA - He said "my copy of Parallels is booting my Bootcamp install"—so it sounds to me as if that's exactly what he's doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get my Macbook Pro to run the same licensed copy of Windows 7 Ultimate on both Bootcamp and Parallels 5 by activating it on both.  I was having trouble running and activating it on my Parallels VM which ran the Bootcamp install.  So what I did was change the MAC address of eth0 to match the one from Bootcamp.

Once I changed that, I called Microsoft and activated via their automated system, which generated a set of numbers/code for me.

Comment: This is the “more proper” way to do it.

Comment: +1 That was the advice I was given by Parallels too. I think this may work for 3rd-party software makers too.